# How to enable git on existing TFS project?

Tags: tfs

Environment: Visual Studio 2017, TFS project set at visual studio online.

I am working on a community project. The source code is checked into TFS project using the free account provided by visual studio online.

I now need to enable git on this project such that others can use from other projects.

On TFS online, I see a way to create a new GIT-based project but I don't see any option to enable GIT on an existing TFS project. I remember to have used this option long time ago. Wondering where I can find this switch. Or, is there any easy way to migrate existing code to GIT. Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **Import repository** to import the Git repository from TFVC.

1. From the repo drop-down, select **Import repository**.
2. Select TFVC from the **Source type** dropdown
3. Type the path to the repository / branch / folder that you want to
   import to the Git repository. For example,
   `$/0522TFVCScrum/BuildProcessTemplates`
4. If you want to migrate history from the TFVC repository, click
   **Migrate history** and select the number of days. You can migrate up to
   180 days of history starting from the most recent changeset. A link
   to the TFVC repository is added in the commit message of the 1st
   changeset that is migrated to Git. This makes it easy to find older
   history when needed.
5. Give a name to the new Git repository and click **Import**. Depending on
   the size of the import, your Git repository would be ready in a few
   minutes.

Refer to this article for details: [Import repositories from TFVC to Git](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/import-from-tfvc)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Hover over the Code tab, click "Manage Repositories", then click the "New Repository" button.